# There isn't highlighting on a profile's page description

Tags: bug, profile-page, syntax-highlighting

I don't know if this is intentional, but the **description on profile page didn't highlight**, even using the correct formatting, as below:

> [image: Profile description formatting]

This might be a **bug** since while we're editing our description, there's highlighting:

> [image: Profile description editing]

This is how the description is showed at the [profile's page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11578778/brhaka?tab=profile).

> [image: brhaka profile description]

Comment: That is status-bydesign: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252222/code-syntaxhighlighting-does-not-work-in-about-me/252253#252253

Comment: as a side note `searchOnStackOverflow()` will always through an exception. You can optimize your code by keeping `searchOnGoogle()` which also include results from StackOverflow

Comment: You can use `searchOnGoogle("site:stackoverflow.com " + term)` to get results from just Stack Overflow too :).

Comment: Thanks for that tricks guys! I used `searchOnStackOverflow()` and `searchOnGoogle()` just for fun, but good to know that they can really work. :)